# Copying the contents of a listbox to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I have a functioning listbox in TkInter and am trying to create a function that allows the user to delete a line of data. The contents of the listbox are from a text file  (userfile). I would like to be able to select a line from the listbox and have it be deleted from the listbox and the text file. I currently have the line being deleted from the listbox via curselection, however not from the corresponding text file. I do not know if it is possible to delete a certain line from the text file and was wondering if copying the contents of the listbox to the text file would be the best way ?

```
def Delete():

    global rootD
    global userfile
    global listbox1

    rootD = Tk()
    rootD.title('Delete info')

    fin = open(userfile, 'r')
    mylist = fin.readlines()
    fin.close()

    listbox1 = Listbox(rootD, width=50, height=6)
    listbox1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    yscroll = Scrollbar(command=listbox1.yview, orient=VERTICAL)
    yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N + S)
    listbox1.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)

    enter1 = Label(rootD, text='Click on the line to delete', width=50)
    enter1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    for item in mylist:
        listbox1.insert(END, item)

    delButton = Button(rootD, text='Delete', command=Remove)
    delButton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    delButton.grid(row=2, column=0)

def Remove():

    global listbox1
    global nameEL          # a previous input for the username
    global userfile

    try:
        index = listbox1.curselection()[0]
        listbox1.delete(index)
        newfile = nameEL.get() + '.txt'
        with open(newfile, 'w') as u:
            u.write(listbox1.get(0, END))
            u.write('\n')
            u.close()
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: It would probably be easiest to just write the contents of the `Listbox` to the file. It's possible to delete a line in text file, but that typically involves reading the entire thing into memory and then writing it back out again without the selected line (or reading and writing it line-by-line, skipping any that have been deleted).

Comment: And how would I copy the contents of the listbox to a text file in the correct format ? I am currently getting a TypeError: must be str, not list error but would still like the format of the text file in the form of a list with each item on a different line

Comment: It would help to see the code that's causing the problem instead of me guessing. Something like `for line in listbox_contents:`,  `file.write(line + '\n')`.

Comment: You can retrieve the contents with `listbox_contents = listbox1.get(0, END)`

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(listbox1.get(0, END)))
    f.write('\n'
    f.close()
```